# Logout In React using Persist

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have set up login in my react app rootReducer.js in the following way:-

```
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'parkytAdmin',
    storage: storage,
    whitelist : ['users']
}
const authPersistConfig = {
    key: 'user', 
    storage:storageSession 
}; // This is to session storage

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    // other reducers //
    users               : persistReducer(authPersistConfig,userReducer),
});

export default persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

Now I want to log out. How can I do that?